# Identify SQL time format

Tags: sql, sqlite

I found this representation of a date (and time?) in an SQLite database. I don't recognize it as anything standard like UNIX timestamp, can anybody help me to identify it?

`498586831.475129` or `497469155.776235`

sometimes however, it is only one number (without the .).

Some context: I expect the value to be a date (and likely also time, probably to the nearest second) which is post 2007 and not in the future.

More info: The SQLite field type is `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `TIMESTAMP` values are likely from Apple Core Foundation code based on an epoch of Jan 1, 2001 00:00:00 GMT.

> [Time Utilities - Core Foundation | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/time_utilities)
>
> Core Foundation measures time in units of seconds. The base data type
>   is the `CFTimeInterval`, which measures the difference in seconds
>   between two times. Fixed times, or dates, are defined by the
>   `CFAbsoluteTime` data type, which measures the time interval between a
>   particular date and the absolute reference date of Jan 1 2001 00:00:00
>   GMT.

[Wolfram Alpha: January 1, 2001 00:00:00 GMT + 498586831.475129 seconds](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=January%201,%202001%2000:00:00%20GMT%20%2B%20498586831.475129%20seconds)
Result:  4:20:31 GMT | Wednesday, October 19, 2016

[Wolfram Alpha: January 1, 2001 00:00:00 GMT + 497469155.776235 seconds](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=January%201,%202001%2000:00:00%20GMT%20%2B%20497469155.776235%20seconds)
Result: 5:52:35 GMT | Thursday, October 6, 2016

---

**Prior answer (still relevant)**

Without more context, you must look for conversions that make sense.

The integer part is a reasonable number of seconds, and the decimal places could represent microseconds.

**Option 1: UNIX Epoch**

> [Wolfram Alpha: 498586831.475129 seconds since unix epoch](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=498586831.475129%20seconds%20since%20unix%20epoch)
>
> Corresponding Gregorian time and date:
>
> 4:20:31 pm UTC | Saturday, October 19, 1985

Is a date in 1985 reasonable for that record?

**Option 2: Alternate Epoch**

> [Wolfram Alpha: 498586831.475129 seconds ago](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=498586831.475129%20seconds%20ago)
>
> Result:
>
> 9:43:46 pm EDT | Sunday, July 22, 2001

Perhaps, the field represented seconds since January 1, 2000 or January 1, 2001.

**Option 3: Duration**

> [Wolfram Alpha: 498586831.475129 seconds](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=498586831.475129%20seconds)
>
> Unit conversions:
>
> 8.3097805245855×10^6 minutes
>
> 138496.342076425 hours
>
> 5770.680919851 days
>
> 15.799587725555 average Gregorian years

Is this amount of time relevant to the record?

**EDIT:** With your additional context (of the date being between 2007 and the present), "Option 2: Alternate Epoch" becomes the most reasonable, and this record occurs about 15.8 years afterwards.

Comment: It is indeed from an iOS app, well spotted :)